# Make element behave a certain way until event (Making a pacman game)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I'm making a pacman game in Javascript as an exercise. What would be a good way to make the character go one direction indefinitely until another key is pressed?

```
function Player(){

this.left = $('#pacMan').css('left');

this.leftMove = function(){

this.left = parseInt(this.left) - 20;  
$('#pacMan').animate({'left': this.left}, 100);   
};


//Pressing directional keys calls appropriate methods.

$('body').keydown(function(){
if (event.which === 39){
for (i=0; i<13; i++){
pacMan.rightMove();
}
}
if (event.which === 37){
pacMan.leftMove();
}
if (event.which === 38){
pacMan.topMove();
}
if (event.which === 40){
pacMan.bottomMove();
}

});*/
```

How do I make it so the element keeps moving a direction until a new key is pressed, where it would go in that direction?

Answer (score 1):

A general approach I tend to use for this type of problem is have your object have a `changeX` (`vx`) and a `changeY` (`vy`) variable. Then in your main game loop change the position of the object by those to variables:

```
this.left = parseInt(this.left) - this.vx;  
this.top = parseInt(this.top) - this.vy;
```

In your event handler you would set the vales of `vx` and `vy` depending on where you want to move. For example setting `vx = 10` and `vy = 0` would make it move left by 10 units each loop.

```
if (event.which === 39) {
   //pacMan.leftMove();
   pacMan.vx = 10; pacMan.vy = 0;
}
```

The player would simply have a `move()` function that would move based on those values in the main loop:

```
var timer = setInterval(function () {
  pacMan.move();
}, 50);
```

Where `move()` is:

```
this.move = function(){
  this.left = parseInt(this.left) - this.vx;  
  $('#pacMan').css({'left': this.left})
  this.top = parseInt(this.top) - this.vy;  
  $('#pacMan').css({'top': this.top});      
}
```

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/e6mumbwa/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setTimeout function for that

```
setTimeout( function() {
    // leftMove, topMove, bottomMove, rightMove
    // if you press new key, you have to change direction
} , 1000 );
// 1000 moving delay
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using `window.setInterval`, something like this should work

```
var timer;
$('body').keydown(function () {
  var key = event.which;
  window.clearInterval(timer);
  timer = window.setInterval(function () {
    switch (key) {
    case 37:
      pacMan.leftMove();
      break;
    case 38:
      pacMan.topMove();
      break;
    case 39:
      pacMan.rightMove();
      break;
    case 40:
      pacMan.bottomMove();
      break;
    }
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, brother. Never thought of that :DD

Comment: You're right, I had the scope of `event` wrong. Try the updated code.

Comment: YES IT WORKED. Thanks I totally see the issue as well. Yeah the event is not in the scope of the keydown function (which it should be referring to) Thanks again.